# Using the "foreach" option in TikZ to make a table

Tags: tikz-pgf

To show that the probability of rolling two die and getting a sum of 7 is 1/6, I wanted to make a table using "foreach" option in `TikZ`. The following code gives me a table of all the possible rolls.

The rectangles of adjacent pairs overlap.  This makes for an unseemly appearance.  How can I add horizontal space to separate the rectangles?

Using this code, can I replace the rectangles containing the six pairs of numbers that total 7 with a circle or ellipse?

How can I make the first number blue and the second number green?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node foreach \x in {1,...,6} foreach \y in{1,...,6} [draw] at (\x-6,6-\y)
{(\x, \, \y)};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
    \node foreach \x in {1,...,6} foreach \y in{1,...,6} [draw, circle] at (\x-6,6-\y)
    {(\textcolor{blue}{\x}, \, \textcolor{green}{\y})};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.8cm,y=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {%
        \foreach \y in {1,...,6} {%
            \draw (\x-6,6-\y) ellipse (.8cm and .3cm) node {$(\textcolor{blue}{\x},\textcolor{green}{\y})$};            
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**:

Sorry, I got you wrong in the first place. Here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.8cm,y=1cm]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {%
        \foreach \y in {1,...,6} {%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\test}{\x+\y};
            \ifthenelse{\test=7}
            {\draw (\x-6,6-\y) ellipse (.8cm and .3cm) node {$(\textcolor{blue}{\x},\textcolor{green}{\y})$};}
            {\draw (\x-6,6-\y) node [draw] {$(\textcolor{blue}{\x},\textcolor{green}{\y})$};}                        
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I only want the pair of numbers that total 7 to be enclosed by a circle or ellipse.  The others pairs should be enclosed by rectangles ... or not enclosed.

Comment: What does the option `[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]` instruct `TikZ` to do?  A reference to the manual would be helpful.

Comment: @Adelyn Sorry, I got you wrong. I made an edit at the end of my answer. The option you are asking for is redefining the size of the coordinate system of your graphic. I believe, the default is 1cm. You have given unitless coordinates such as `(\x-6,6-\y)`. Therefore, I just told the tikzpicture to interpret this as  `((\x-6)*1.5 cm,(6-\y)*1.5 cm)`.

Comment: Yes, this is the display that I wanted.  Thanks.  This involves some programming!  Right now, I am learning the usual command for `TikZ`.  Please clarify one feature of your revised code.  Are you saying that the units of the coordinate system are, by default, in centimeters?  If this is the case, the command `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1)` would draw a line segment diagonally that is $\sqrt{2}$ centimeters in length.  Is that correct?  By typing `[x=1.8cm,y=1cm]` immediately after declaring a `TikZ` environment, you are saying to scale both directions by a factor of 1.8.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Adelyn The default coordinates of Ti*k*Z do not have any unit. But there is some default of course. Just do `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0)`, print it, and measure if it is a centimeter. Or you search the manual for this information. But let's say, these are just "tikz-units". If they are too small for you, you can redefine them. `x=3.14in, y=10000pt`; whatever you want.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a matrix and empty cell directives

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric}
% shorthand for less typing
\def\mcr{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}\def\mcc{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [execute at empty cell={\ifnum7=\numexpr\mcc+\mcr\relax
  \node[ellipse,draw,inner sep=1pt]
              {(\textcolor{blue}{\the\mcc},\textcolor{green}{\the\mcr})};
\else
  \node[draw,inner sep=1pt]{(\textcolor{blue}{\the\mcc},\textcolor{green}{\the\mcr})};
\fi}]{&&&&&\\&&&&&\\&&&&&\\&&&&&\\&&&&&\\&&&&&\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I told LaRiFaRi, this is some programming that I did not intend to get involved.  I am learning the basic commands of `TikZ`.  You did give me code that gives me the display that I wanted ... but, for now, I would manually input 36 different nodes.

Comment: @Adelyn No problem. But what is above is basically this sentence: *If the matrix entry is empty, sum it's row and column numbers and check if it is 7 and either do this or that*. So no black magic is involved.

Comment: I have not seen most of the commands in your code:  `\matrix`, `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow`, `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn`, `execute at empty cell=`, and `\fi`.  If I plan to use `TikZ` to make tables, I will refer to your code.  I would have to get more familiar with `TikZ` commands.  It will take awhile.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An attempt with MetaPost, as sober as possible. To be processed with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 1.25cm; v := -cm; pair pos; path box; picture dices;
    beginfig(1);
      for i = 1 upto 6:
        for j = 1 upto 6:
          pos := ((i+1)*u, (j+1)*v);
          dices :=  thelabel(decimal i & ", " & decimal j, pos);
          box := bbox dices;
          if i+j <> 7: draw box;
          else:
            d1 := xpart(lrcorner box - llcorner box) + labeloffset;
            d2 := ypart(urcorner box - lrcorner box) + labeloffset;
            draw fullcircle xscaled d1 yscaled d2 shifted  pos;
          fi
          draw dices; 
        endfor
      endfor
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]